# Matlab delete specific elements from an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, vector

I have for example `a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];` and I have to delete each 2 following numbers from 3.

like at the end it should be `a=[1 4 7 10];`

How to do this without a for loop.

And also if there is a way to guarantee that at the end the resulting array will have exact number of entries, like here it should be `a` with 4 entries at the end.

But for example we have `b=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ];` and if I want make sure that at the end I still have 4 entries in the rest array, so that `b` can't be equal to `[1 4 7]` because I need 4 entries for sure.

Comment: What result do you want to get with `b=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]; ` ?

Comment: If `a = 1:10;`,  `a(1:3:10)` outputs `[1, 4, 7, 10]`

Comment: i wanna get b=[1 4  7  9 ]; because i need exactly 4 entries, but if i delete each times 2 entries i would get  b=[1 4  7]; so thats why the deletion of the last portion of an array must remove not 2 but just one entry to make sure that i will have 4 entries left in an array, like i have to create some kind of IF or MAKE SURE  conditions that array at the very end contains 4 entries but not 3.

Comment: What outputs exactly are you expecting? for example,  if `b=[1 2 3]` and if `b=1:6` and if `b=1:15` . It's still not clear what outputs you want when, at the end, the length of the array is lesser than and greater than 4

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexing for this:

```
A = 1:10;
B = A(1:3:end)
B =
    [1 4 7 10]
```

Or, if you really want to remove elements:

```
A = 1:10;
A(2:3:end) = [];
A(3:3:end) = [];
```

For your second question regarding length checking, it's unclear what you're asking. Would an if comparison be enough ?

```
if numel(A) ~= 4

    % ... Handle unexpected values here

end
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question and in the comments that you need 4 elements  at the end and if elements are less than 4 then you want to include the last element/s of `b`, the following should work:-

```
b=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 

b_req=b(1:3:end);
temp=length(b_req);
if temp<4  b_req(end+1:4)=b(end-3+temp:end);    % for including the elements of b so that total elements are 4 at the end
elseif temp>4 b_req=b_req(1:4);                 % for removing the extra elements
end
b_req
```

**Output:-**

```
b = 
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9

b_req =
     1     4     7     9
```

and
if instead `b=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];` then the same code gives what you require, i.e. 
`b_req = [1 4 7 10]`

Answer (score 0):

This code speaks for itself:

```
a = 1:15; % some vector
% returns every third element after the first one:
third_elemets = a(1:3:end);
% returns the missing elements for the vector to be in size 4 from the end of a
last_elements = a(end-3+length(third_elemets):end);
% take maximum 4 elements from a
logic_ind = true(min(4,length(third_elemets)),1);
% and concatanate them with last_elements (if there are any)
a = [third_elemets(logic_ind) last_elements]
```

and under the assumption that whenever there are less than 4 elements you simply take the last one(s) - it should always work.

Comment: What's the point of a one-liner here ? It won't go particularly faster and it is awfull to read and maintain ... note that I appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: @Ratbert This line also handles most cases of less than 4-element vector in the output.

Comment: Why comment was not on what the line is actually doing, but on why would a one liner be preferable here, as compared as the other solutions.

Comment: Writing in one line is not preferable, and not needed, it was just a short way  of writing it. I  agree it is not so readable, that's why I added the explanation, but any how, I'll edit it to a more readable form ;)

Comment: @Ratbert there you go... a much more readable form, isn't it?